# Whenever a user selects and Option and changes it saves all of the previous options in Reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have a drop down list and everything works with the dropdown list unless a user picks an option and then changes the option. If this happens it gives me all of the options they selected not just the final option. I am unsure of why this behavior exists. I have tried changing the handlers to onclick and so forth but this does not help..

```
import "../App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { checkRef } from "./firebase";

function Interface() {
  const [choices, setChoices] = useState({
    selectValue: "Pick Reason",
    damageValue: "Pick Reason",
    submitted: true,
    default: "Pick Option",
    screen: 0,
    keys: 0,
    trackpad: 0,
    headphneJack: 0,
    battery: 0,
    other: 0
  });

  let handleCart = function(e) {
    return setChoices({ ...choices, selectValue: e.target.value });
  };

  let handleDamage = function(e) {
    if (e.target.value === "Broken Screen") {
      return setChoices({
        ...choices,

        screen: +1
      });
      //
    } else if (e.target.value === "Broken Keys") {
      return setChoices({
        ...choices,

        keys: +1
      });
    } else if(e.target.value === "Won't Charge"){
        return setChoices({
            ...choices,

            battery: +1
        })
    } else if(e.target.value === "Trackpad"){
        return setChoices({
            ...choices,

            trackpad: +1
        })
    }
    //

    //
    else {
      return setChoices({ ...choices, damageValue: e.target.value });
    }
  };

  let buttonSub = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const item = {
      reason: choices.damageValue,
      teacher: choices.selectValue,
      screen: choices.screen,
      keys: choices.keys,
      battery: choices.battery,
      trackpad: choices.trackpad
    };
    checkRef.push().set(item);
    setChoices({
      selectValue: "",
      damageValue: "",
      submitted: false,
      screen: 0,
      keys: 0,
      battery: 0,
      trackpad: 0
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Chromebook Deposit Form</h1>
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Choose what grade you're in</label>
          <select
            className="form-control w-50 "
            id="cart"
            onChange={handleCart}
            value={choices.selectValue}
          >
            <option>{choices.default}</option>
            <option>6th Grade</option>
            <option>7th Grade</option>
            <option>8th Grade</option>
          </select>
          <hr></hr>
          <label>Select Your Reason For deposit</label>
          <select
            className="form-control w-50 "
            id="cart"
            value={choices.damageValue}
            onChange={handleDamage}
          >
            <option>{choices.default}</option>
            <option>Broken Screen</option>
            <option>Broken Keys</option>
            <option>Won't Charge</option>
            <option>Trackpad</option>
            <option>Other</option>
          </select>

          <button className="button" onClick={buttonSub}>
            Submit Information
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Interface;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you always return `{ ...choices }`
with some other value. `...choices` takes everything from the object `choices` and puts it into the new object you return.

Remove those from your code, and just overwrite all values to zero except for the one you need to set, or change your code to something that makes more sense like a string value indicating what option is selected.